# Too much recursion mousehover

Tags: jquery, dictionary, mouseover

I have the following code to highlight diferent areas of a map(For example, when an state is fisically separated, and the user do mouse-over in a part of the state, the whole state must be hilighted):

```
$(function() {
$('#area-a').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#area-b').mouseover();
    $('#area-c').mouseover();
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $('#area-b').mouseout();
    $('#area-c').mouseout();
});


$(function() {
$('#area-b').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#area-a').mouseover();
    $('#area-c').mouseover();   
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    $('#area-a').mouseout();
    $('#area-c').mouseout();
});
```

});

So, I am getting Too much recursion error, I can see why that's happening and I found that event.stopPropagation() is the way to solve it, but if I place it at the beginning of the function, it doesn't highlight all the areas, so I am stuck. Is this the correct way to highlight different areas or should I place the stopPropagation  event somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post a (non-)working jsfiddle?

Comment: I feel like you could go about this a different way. Would need to see the markup though. When you mouseover an element the others should have the mousout fired automatically unless they are children... you really shouldnt have to manually call them.

Comment: There are better ways instead of triggering mouseover!

Comment: Can't you call your highlight function / apply the style changes directly instead of triggering mouseover?

Comment: silent4w: how do I post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Loktar when I mouseover a sub-area, the mouseover event is fired, but only for that sub-area. I need to highlight three related subareas, and thats why I am using those functions.